# Clarification on Docker Compose's `start_period` parameter

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to understand how the [`start_period` works with Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck).  If we have the following as a Healthcheck:

```
--start-period=60s --retries=2
```

Does that mean that Docker Swarm will try twice, each time wait 60 sec before considering the container Unhealthy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yup exactly.

Start period provides initialization time for containers that need time to bootstrap. Probe failure during that period will not be counted towards the maximum number of retries. However, if a health check succeeds during the start period, the container is considered started and all consecutive failures will be counted towards the maximum number of retries.

Comment: And so it does not keep the service from starting ? It does not offer a way to delay the start of a service so as to give time to another service ?

Comment: @Stephane, I think you're looking for `deploy.restart_policy.delay`.

Comment: FYI here are the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck